# Как сделать выборку из MySQL по трем полям с несколькими условиями?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Есть таблица `table`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `main` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nid` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table`(
      `main`, `sid`, `rid`, `nid`
  ) VALUES(
    1, 8, 1, null),
    (1, null, null, "привет"),
    (2, 8, 1, null),
    (2, 1, 2, null),
    (1, 1, 2, null)
```

**Нужно найти такое поле `main`, где есть записи**

```
sid = 8, rid=1, nid = null ;
sid = null, rid = null, nid = "привет"
sid=1, rid=2, nid = null
```

Можно выбрать так записи за один запрос?

```
$d = array(
    array('sid' => 8, 'rid' => 1, 'nid' => null),
    array('sid' => null, 'rid' => null, 'nid' => 'привет'),
    array('sid' => 1, 'rid' => 2, 'nid' => null),
);
//$d - не обязательно должен содержать 3 записи
```

Объясню на шагах, так как иначе не могу:

1. Берем данные: sid = 8, rid=1, nid = null
2. Выборка должна дать две записи с main =1 и main =2,
3. Добавляем условие: sid = null, rid = null, nid = "привет"
4. Выборка должна вернуть только одну запись с main=1

К сожалению, больше не знаю как объяснить. Это фильтр. Мне нужно найти записи к которым указаны несколько (sid, rid, nid) и записи должны включать именно все указанные данные.

Comment: @stasQa, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю правильно ли понял, вот 2 варианта:

1. ```
   WHERE (sid = 8 AND rid=1 AND nid = null) OR (sid = null AND rid = null AND nid = "привет") OR (sid=1 AND rid=2 AND nid = null)
   ```
2. ```
   WHERE sid IN (8,1) AND rid IN (1,2) AND nid = "Привет"
   ```

Comment: Нет, к сожалению это не то..

Comment: @evz, @stasQa, чтобы выбрать null поля, необходимо использовать конструкцию IS NULL:

1) WHERE (sid = 8 AND rid=1 AND nid IS NULL) OR (sid IS NULL AND rid IS NULL AND nid = "привет") OR (sid=1 AND rid=2 AND nid IS NULL)

Comment: я понимаю про is null. ваш вариант отобразит и 1 и 2.